# How to get the generators of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ in the paper by Fidkowski and Kitaev?

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-field-theory, topological-order, topological-phase, majorana-fermions

In the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0904.2197) by Fidkowski and Kitaev, they aim to study the interaction of 8 parallel Majorana wires, and they work on $\mathfrak{so(8)}$ Lie Algebra. They first start with just 4 parallel Majorana wires which in $\mathfrak{so}(2n)$, $n=2$. Then based on the fact that $\mathfrak{so(4)}\cong\mathfrak{so(3)}\oplus\mathfrak{so(3)}$, they aim to get the generators of two copies of $\mathfrak{so(3)}$ (which I do not understand why they used two copies of $\mathfrak{so(3)}$ rather than just one $\mathfrak{so(4)}$?).  The map of Lie algebra is defined:
\begin{align}
\rho(A)=\frac{i}{4} \sum\limits_{j,k=1}^{2n} A_{jk}\hat{c}_j\hat{c}_k
\end{align}
Where $A \in \mathfrak{so}(2n)$ is an anti-symmetric matrix belonging to the Lie algebra. So here we have $n=2$ and 4 Majoranas $\{\hat{c}_1,\hat{c}_2,\hat{c}_3,\hat{c}_4\}$.
I have three questions:

1. Here $\rho$ is the adjoint representation? Base on the relation

\begin{align}
[-i\rho(A),-i\rho(B)]=-i\rho([A,B])
\end{align}

Therefore $\rho$ defines a Lie algebra, so is it the adjoint representation? Also, I am not sure why I am not able to finish the proof of the above equation. Here is my attempt (I know I got the commutation of $A$ and $B$ but I do not know how to get the other direction:

\begin{align}
[-i\rho(A),-i\rho(B)]&=-i(\frac{i}{4})^2 \sum\limits_{j,k=1}^{2n} \sum\limits_{j',k'1}^{2n'}(A_{jk}\hat{c}_j\hat{c}_k B_{j'k'}\hat{c}_{j'}\hat{c}_{k'}-B_{j'k'}\hat{c}_{j'}\hat{c}_{k'}A_{jk}\hat{c}_j\hat{c}_k)\\
&=-i(\frac{i}{4})^2 \sum\limits_{j,k=1}^{2n} \sum\limits_{j',k'1}^{2n'}(A_{jk} B_{j'k'}-B_{j'k'}A_{jk})\hat{c}_j\hat{c}_k\hat{c}_{j'}\hat{c}_{k'}\\
&=...
\end{align}

2. How the induced action on $\hat{c}$ is defined as follows?
   \begin{align}
   \hat{c}_l \rightarrow i[\rho(A),c_l]
   \end{align}
   I cannot understand this induced action? and they did not even define $c_l$.
3. My big question is that how under $\rho$ the generators of two $\mathfrak{so(3)}$ obey equations (5) and (6) in the reference. I know $\mathfrak{so(4)}$ has 6 generators.
   \begin{align}
   &A_1=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0& -1 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0
   \end{array}\right] \quad A_2=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0& 0& 0 \\
   -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0
   \end{array}\right] \quad A_3=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
   0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0
   \end{array}\right] \\
   &B_1=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
   0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
   0 & 0& 0& 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0
   \end{array}\right] \quad B_2=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0& 0& -1 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0
   \end{array}\right] \quad B_3=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
   0 & 0& 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0
   \end{array}\right] \\
   \end{align}

So as the paper addressed both $A_i$ and $B_i$ belong to $\mathfrak{so(4)}$, but I don't understand how to get the generators.

Comment: About your second question: the $l$ is just a dummy index ($l = 1,2,3,4$), so $\hat{c}_l$ is just one of the Majorana operators of Eq.(3). Notice that there is an index $l$ on the left side of the arrow too: $\hat{c}_l \rightarrow i[\rho(A),\hat{c}_l]$.

Comment: @LucasBaldo I understand that $l$ is a dummy variable. However, there are $c$ and $\hat{c}$ in the paper. Also, I do not know why and how he did this map.

Comment: My apologies, I had not noticed the missing "^" in some $c$'s. That is really odd to me. Do you think it's possible it's a typo? The $c_l$ on the right-hand-side of Eq.(4) should be acting in Fock space, just like $\rho(A)$, in order for the expression to make sense, in my opinion. Weird nonetheless. Also, I'm also having trouble understanding where this map comes from. I'll let you know if I can think of anything.

Comment: I think you are right, $c$s should be $\hat{c}$. Also, this is an induced action in Lie algebra and we need a tangent space. I don't know how to relate the mathematical definition to this form of Lie Algebra.

Comment: I've been reading more on the paper and I cannot understand why the authors state that the $T$ symmetry of the system satisfies $\hat{T}^2 = 1$, instead of $\hat{T}^2 = (-1)^{\hat{N}}$.  Do you know why is it like this?

Comment: In their other [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.4138?context=cond-mat), you can see they got the result for $k$ odd and even, where $k$ is a band topological index. As you see in the  _VI_ section, they got for $k=0, 1, 2, 7$ $T^2=+1$ which is the case for this paper. I am not sure here why he used it!